# Pattern match query in a Oracle table

Tags: regex, oracle

My requirement is, I have two tables `test_ref` and `test_data`.

`test_ref` table records:

```
Pattern
--------------
Delhi
Chennai
Bangalore
Calcutta
Hyderabad
```

`test_data` table recrods:

```
SlNo  descrpt
--------------------------------------------------

1    Very code and hot in Delhi, is the north part of india
2    Calcutta is famous for fish
3    This is first correct message to return
4    Very hot and nice in Chennai city
5    green and clean city is the Bangalore
6    Kochi is famous for travel
7    This is second correct message to return
```

Now I have to search my pattern from `test_ref` table with the column of `descrpt` from the table `test_data` and result has to be

```
SlNo  descrpt
--------------------------------------------------

3    This is first correct message to return
6    Kochi is famous for travel
7    This is second correct message to return
```

Here

- `Delhi` is present in first record of test_data table, so should eliminate.
- `Calcutta` is present in third row  of test_data table, so should eliminate.
- The pattern which is not found in test_data table should have to return.

Please suggest oracle query for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker has made no attempt to code anything themself.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use regular expressions for this:

**Oracle 11g Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_ref ( pattern ) AS 
SELECT 'Delhi'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chennai'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bangalore' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Calcutta'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hyderabad' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test_data ( SlNo, descrpt ) AS
SELECT 1,    'Very code and hot in Delhi, is the north part of india' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    'Calcutta is famous for fish' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    'This is first correct message to return' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    'Very hot and nice in Chennai city' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    'green and clean city is the Bangalore' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    'Kochi is famous for travel' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,    'This is second correct message to return' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test_data d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                    FROM    test_ref r
                    WHERE   INSTR( d.descrpt, r.Pattern  ) > 0 );
```

**Result**:

```
      SLNO DESCRPT                                                
---------- ------------------------------------------------------
         3 This is first correct message to return                
         6 Kochi is famous for travel                             
         7 This is second correct message to return
```

You could also use:

- `WHERE d.descrpt LIKE '%'||r.Pattern||'%'` or
- `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( d.descrpt, r.pattern )` (if you really did want to use a regular expression).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to do this with big data sets, but the following works:

```
with temp as
(
    select 'Delhi Chennai Bangalore Calcutta Hyderabad' Pattern  from dual
),
test_data as
(         select 1 sino,   'Very code and hot in Delhi, is the north part of india' descrpt from dual
union all select 2 sino,   'Calcutta is famous for fish' descrpt from dual
union all select 3 sino,   'This is first correct message to return' descrpt from dual
union all select 4 sino,   'Very hot and nice in Chennai city' descrpt from dual
union all select 5 sino,   'green and clean city is the Bangalore' descrpt from dual
union all select 6 sino,   'Kochi is famous for travel' descrpt from dual
union all select 7 sino,   'This is second correct message to return' descrpt from dual)
select sino, descrpt
from test_data 
where sino not in (select sino
                   from  test_data t2
                         -- the next query breaks the pattern into individual words
                        ,(select distinct
                          trim(regexp_substr(t.Pattern, '[^ ]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as word
                        from 
                          temp t,
                          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.pattern, '[^ ]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels) wrds
                   where t2.descrpt like '%'||wrds.word||'%')
```

Comment: The source code of the original post makes it appear that the city names in the pattern are all in different rows but that all got mangled when converting to HTML format. I've tidied the post up to make this clearer and that ought to make your solution a lot simpler.

Comment: Well in that case you've got it covered. I'll leave mine up though just in case any masochists want to see what hoops you can find yourself jumping through if you design your data poorly ;-)